# Mesh to Curves without overlap

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have the following mesh:

[image: my mesh]

Using the `Edge Paths to Curves` and `Shortest Edge Paths` node (with the Vertex at the 3D-Cursor chosen as the `End Vertex`) I can convert it into `Curves` like so:

[image: overlapping curves]

However this "overlap" between the curves leads to issues when trying to add a profile to them. What I'm trying to achieve is an effect similar to the `Skin Modifier`.

Is there any way to get the following kind of curve topology?

[image: no more overlap]

Comment: Not really. A curve cannot branch, each control point on a spline can only have a maximum of two segments connected to it. Either just one segment when it's an endpoint or two segments when it is inbetween two segments. So converting it into a mesh to merge it for example with a _Skin_ modifier as you mentioned is the only way.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Sorry if I was unclear with my question. I do know that a curve cannot branch, what I meant was how to make one of the curves shorter.

Comment: You could try *Curve to Mesh > Merge Vertices > Mesh to Curve*